# Why is interpolate.splev() not evaluating the point I provide in the x argument?

Tags: python, scipy

**I want to evaluate a spline, which is defined by `x` and `y` on a third point `pointToEvaluate` (here 0), but it doesn't evaluate the point I pass to it.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x = (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
y = (1, 0, 1, 4, 9)
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x,y], s=0)

pointToEvaluate = 0
xPoints, yPoints = interpolate.splev(pointToEvaluate, tck)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')
ax.plot(xPoints, yPoints, 'bo')
plt.show()
print(xPoints, yPoints)
```

It should print the values for (xPoints, yPoints) as (0.0, 0.0), but it returns: (-1.0000000000000002 1.0). In the image:
[image: Red are my own lines. The blue point is the value, which should be evaluated on x]

**I am obviously using interpolate.splev() the wrong way, but I don't know where.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with splrep, which is the one-dimensional version of splprep.

In the case of splprep, splev says

> x : array_like
>
> An array of points at which to return the value of the smoothed spline or its derivatives. If tck was returned from splprep, then the parameter values, u should be given.

So then, I would have guessed that one needs to provide `u` keyword to splprep

> u : array_like, optional
>
> An array of parameter values. If not given, these values are calculated automatically as M = len(x[0]), where
>
> v[0] = 0
>
> v[i] = v[i-1] + distance(x[i], x[i-1])
>
> u[i] = v[i] / v[M-1]

However, I cannot manage to make it work this way...

Additionally, there is the more recent make_interp_spline (have a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#d-splines)). Examples for both this latter and splrep give:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x = (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
y = (1, 0, 1, 4, 9)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)
b = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, y)
pointsToEvaluate = (0,)
yPoints1 = interpolate.splev(pointsToEvaluate, tck)
yPoints2 = b(pointsToEvaluate)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')
ax.plot(pointsToEvaluate, yPoints1, 'bo', markersize=15)
ax.plot(pointsToEvaluate, yPoints2, 'ws')
plt.show()
```

and display

[image]

Comment: I tried using `u`, too, but that doesn't let me evaluate new points, only returns the existing ones. I guess, I fundamentally misunderstand something about B-Splines. `make_interp_spline` works like a charm though, so thank you.

Comment: What I meant is that you can provide `u` as a keyword argument to splprep, but I do not understand how that works.